# Loop and check two array always return only one element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I´m have two arrays, one is an array of string `['security', 'hobbies']` and the other is and array of object `[{name: 'randome', category: 'hobbies'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'randome'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'randome'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'security'}]`, i´m trying to loop both arrays and `splice` all those objects that doesn´t match with the categories on the first array but always get only one element in the loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < searchparam.category.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < validapps.length; j++) {
          let match: boolean = false;
          if (validapps[j].category === searchparam.category[i]) {
            console.log(validapps[j])
            match = true;
            return;
          }
          if (!match) {
            validapps.splice(j, 1);
            j--;
          }
        }
 }
```

after looping i should get 2 or more elements but always get only one.
the resulting data is always one element.

```
_id: "598c69259fe2ff5fd0432396"
active: true
app_language: Array [ "DE" ]
application_code: "ASF"
blacklist: Array []
category: "utilities"
comments: ""
contacts: Array [ "598c40cf0f05ba5d0c5da01a", "598c66d59fe2ff5fd043238a", "59ce05683d7daf37702c1fc1", … ]
id: "598c69259fe2ff5fd0432396"
image: ""
insertDate: "2017-08-10T14:09:41.189Z"
name: "Alpha SSD Fresh"
os: Array [ {…} ]
updateDate: "2017-08-10T14:09:41.608Z"
```

Comment: please add the result of the given data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use `filter`

```
var arr = [{name: 'randome', category: 'hobbies'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'randome'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'randome'}, {name: 'randome', category: 'security'}];
var validItems = ['security', 'hobbies'];
arr = arr.filter( s => validItems.indexOf( s.category ) != -1 ); //only those items will be passed through which have valid categories
```

or

```
arr = arr.filter( s => validItems.includes( s.category ) ); //only those items will be passed through which have valid categories
```

Comment: Why not `includes` then?

Comment: @JonasW. yeah, that works as well. I prefer `indexOf` due to better browser support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility